# How does one install nagios-plugins-all RPM on Oracle Linux 9?

Tags: oracle-linux

```
[root@snc-ol93-rhck ~]# uname -r
5.14.0-362.8.1.el9_3.x86_64
```

When I try to install the RPM like so ...

```
[root@snc-ol93-rhck ~]# dnf install https://yum.oracle.com/repo/OracleLinux/OL9/developer/EPEL/x86_64/getPackage/nagios-plugins-all-2.4.0-5.el9.x86_64.rpm
```

I get this error ...

```
Error:
 Problem: package nagios-plugins-all-2.4.0-5.el9.x86_64 from @commandline requires nagios-plugins-disk_smb, but none of the providers can be installed
  - package nagios-plugins-disk_smb-2.4.0-5.el9.x86_64 from ol9_developer_EPEL requires perl(utf8::all), but none of the providers can be installed
  - package nagios-plugins-disk_smb-2.4.0-7.el9.x86_64 from ol9_developer_EPEL requires perl(utf8::all), but none of the providers can be installed
  - package nagios-plugins-disk_smb-2.4.3-1.el9.x86_64 from ol9_developer_EPEL requires perl(utf8::all), but none of the providers can be installed
  - package nagios-plugins-disk_smb-2.4.4-1.el9.x86_64 from ol9_developer_EPEL requires perl(utf8::all), but none of the providers can be installed
  - package nagios-plugins-disk_smb-2.4.6-1.el9.x86_64 from ol9_developer_EPEL requires perl(utf8::all), but none of the providers can be installed
  - package nagios-plugins-disk_smb-2.4.6-2.el9.x86_64 from ol9_developer_EPEL requires perl(utf8::all), but none of the providers can be installed
  - conflicting requests
  - nothing provides perl(Import::Into) needed by perl-utf8-all-0.024-14.el9.noarch from ol9_developer_EPEL
  - nothing provides perl(PerlIO::utf8_strict) needed by perl-utf8-all-0.024-14.el9.noarch from ol9_developer_EPEL
(try to add '--skip-broken' to skip uninstallable packages or '--nobest' to use not only best candidate packages)
```

I am on oracle linux 9.3 RHCK.

```
[root@snc-ol93-rhck ~]# cat /etc/oracle-release
Oracle Linux Server release 9.3
```

Comment: read the error which don't let any doubt open. You used iirc a Dev source which has gone. and now you try to install another that has some Deps that are unmet. We don't know what you have done in the past to this server but it sounds not harmful ;)

Answer (score 0):

I had a nearly identical error message on Oracle Linux 8. Only difference it was referring to nagios-plugins-disk_smb-2.3.3.3-x versions. I tried to exclude the offending _smb package versions from the repo using commands like the below but it didnt work for me.

dnf config-manager --save --setopt ol8_developer_EPEL.exclude=nagios-plugins-2.3.3-3.el8.x86_64

I got it to work by installing Nagios plugins from source according to the guide I found at:  https://kifarunix.com/how-to-install-nagios-plugins-from-source-rhel-centos-oracle-linux/

I then used these docs: https://docs.librenms.org/Extensions/Services/
in order to enable the services within LibreNMS.

These docs explanation of editing config.php didnt make sense to me, so used the docs here: https://community.librenms.org/t/making-changes-persist-in-config-php-when-using-a-docker-container/20422/2

to guide me to convert the LibreNMS config changes to enable services to lnms syntax. My commands were as follows:

su librenms

lmns config:set discover_services true

lmns config:set discover_services_templates true

lmns config:set show_services true

lmns config:set nagios_plugins /usr/local/nagios/libexec

Note the path to the plugins above is how it was on my system. You may need to amend this to suit the path its installed your side. Good Luck!